# GitLab CI - Build not running configured Job(s)

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab CI, integrated with GitLab as well as the recommended secondary server for a runner. Everything appears to be configured correctly. It detects my commits and runs the build steps and I can see the output.

At least for the default job of:

```
git submodule update --init
ls -la
```

I tried adding a second job with just two steps:

```
npm install
gulp ci
```

I'm using `git clone`, so I want to run install every time.

I ran the build, however, it just repeated the first job. I then deleted my second job and just put all the steps together:

```
npm install
gulp ci
git submodule update --init
ls -la
```

However, the output from the build is still exactly the same as it was when it was just the default job. Something like this:

```
cd /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds && git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:<my-git-project-in-gitlab> project-3 && cd project-3 && git checkout aded9a5a66d754ef41504669e09fbd7393490a24
Cloning into 'project-3'...
Note: checking out 'aded9a5a66d754ef41504669e09fbd7393490a24'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at aded9a5... Merge branch 'master' of <my-repo>
cd /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-3 && git reset --hard && git checkout aded9a5a66d754ef41504669e09fbd7393490a24
HEAD is now at aded9a5 Merge branch 'master' of <my-repo>
HEAD is now at aded9a5... Merge branch 'master' of <my-repo>
git submodule update --init
ls -la
<ls file list>
```

Any ideas? Is there some cache I need to clear or button I need to hit (aside from Save Changes on settings, which I did) when I change the build script to make it take affect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a bit user error, a bit poor UI.

I was trying to test my new build settings by going in to a build and pressing "Retry". Apparently, this re-runs the same build steps that were used. It doesn't use the current project build steps.

When I made a new commit to the project itself, it used by new build steps.

As far as I can see, there isn't a button to just run a new build with the current build steps. It seems the only way is to push a new commit to the code base itself. =S

It looks like the only way is to hit Test Settings from Services > GitLab CI via GitLab... however, there is apparently a bug out with that run now: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

currently as of 7.8.1 the only way to do this is to make a commit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i have just upgraded to 7.10.2 of both gitlab and gitlabci and this has fixed several problems for me with builds not being run, these were:
- the test settings link now triggers the builds. 
- builds in branches other than master were not triggered

It hasn't fixed the issue i've had with the merge request page showing
an error trying to connect to the ci server

I would suggest trying the latest builds as much has changed in the last 2 months